# Hazelcast distributed map

Tags: hazelcast, distributed-cache

We have a Hazelcast distributed cache in our application. Cache perform well in low loads, but when the load and the network latency becomes high cache becomes out of sync between nodes. Has anyone observed this behavior before? I used two nodes in my local machine.

Comment: are you within same private network ?

Comment: What means "out of sync between nodes"? Hazelcast partitions data and that said there is only one owner per key not multiple ones that could run out of sync. Also what is the used Hazelcast version ?